# Environment variable in php fpm returns blank when trying to access more than once

Tags: php

Getting the value of the environment variable only once when trying to access it three times.

In my docker container, there is an environment variable:

```
publication="newpublication"
```

I have set the "clear_env=no" in www.conf file as well.

I have a function that is being called multiple times:

```
public function getPublicationName($envname){
   $pubname = getenv($envname);
   return $pubname;
}
```

When this function is called 3 times, the output is like the following:

```
- newpublication
-
-
```

Any reason why this is happening? I need to get the value of the env variable in all those 3 times but I am getting only once.

Comment: Please note that the updated `getPublicationName()` function does not print anything, it just returns the value. Perhaps you're calling it in the middle of some messed up HTML and the browser is not rendering it. It's also possible that your variable is being overwritten somewhere else, or `$envname` does not always contain what you think it does.

Comment: If it is called `getPublicationName()` why does it need a parameter? `return getenv('publication');` would have worked just the same as the function body. Do you call `getPublicationName` somewhere else with a mistyped `$envname`?